# Check if FileUpload is empty using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'd like to check if the file is of the correct type and if a file has been selected. Id dont mind if I can't fit it into one expression. But both have to be true, that is the file is of the right type and a file is selected by the FileUploadControl.

The below code has the working extension checking using regular expression:

```
<li class="three">
    <p>Bulk insert/upload inventory from file</p>
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadControl" accept="csv" runat="server" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="upload"
            ControlToValidate="fileUploadControl" 
            ErrorMessage="Only csv files are allowed" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Cc][Ss][Vv])$)">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="buttonUploadToInventory" runat="server" Text="Upload" ValidationGroup="upload" OnClick="buttonUploadToInventory_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text="Upload status: Nothing uploaded"></asp:Label>
    </div>
 </li>
```

I'd like to add a new clause that checks if a file is selected, so that I can display an error for it in the same label.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `RequiredFieldValidator` to it. The RFV will fire if no file is selected, and if a file is selected the `RegularExpressionValidator` will fire.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadControl" accept="csv" runat="server" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="upload"
                 ControlToValidate="fileUploadControl" 
                 ErrorMessage="Only csv files are allowed" ForeColor="Red"
                 ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Cc][Ss][Vv])$)">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="upload"
                 ControlToValidate="fileUploadControl" 
                 ErrorMessage="Please select a file" ForeColor="Red">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get them to write to the same label or at least the same location. I'm looking at an error message that is offset to the right when the file is not there. I assume this is because they are not writing to the same location.

Comment: I understand you can do this in CSS. But is it possible to have the RegularExpressionValidators write to a label directly?